# Is it possible to verify a signature computed with a X.509 smartcard inside a contract?

Tags: contract-development

I plan to provide a X.509 certificate and a signature as contract parameters. What would be the process to verify the signature in the contract?

Answer (score 0):

According to [X.509 certificate verification in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6919/x-509-certificate-verification-in-solidity) it will be too expensive to calculate the verification.

Comment: The limitation mentioned in that answer should be fixed by EIP 198, which is part of the coming Byzantium fork.

Comment: Cool. Ethereum is evolving :)